# Scanning for doublets in an array after equating upper and lower case letters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, case-insensitive

I'm reading in a file, containing words and names, as a string. Then I'm breaking it into an array of strings. What I want to do is to print out the names that are also words. The words are spelled with only lower case letters and the names has a capital first letter. Thus, I want to order upper and lower cases the same so that Ii then can scan the array and receive the duplicates.

So what I have in my main.m file looks like this now:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    // insert code here...
    NSString *wordString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words"
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:NULL];

    NSArray *words = [wordString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Everywhere it says I should use a caseIntensiveCompare method, but I don't understand how it works, or how to use it in this particularly case.. When I search for it on google all I get is this:

```
NSString *aString = @"ABC";
NSString *bString = @"abc";

if ([aString caseInsesitiveCompare: bString]) == NSOrderedSame)
{
    //The strings are ordered equal
}
```

It seems wrong, firstly because I only have the one string, and secondly I want it to actually order them the letters the same, not to check if they are ordered the same..
If someone could give me a hint of how to do this I would be VERY thankful! 
Thanks in advance // Bjoern

Comment: So overall you need to identify duplicates in array right??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether i have understand your question properly. But how much i understood is you need to first store array string in mutable set then on the basis of that you can compare the existing one to the new one as represent below code. So that like that you can filter your array as well as identify duplicate both words and names. Below assuming words is you array which contains string values. So on the basis of that processing the further code.

```
  NSMutableSet* existing = [NSMutableSet set];
  NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray 
 array];
for (id object in words) {
if (![existing containsObject:[[object     
name]lowercaseString]) {
  [existing addObject:[[object 
  name]lowercaseString];
  [newArray addObject:object];
  }
else 
{
NSLog(@"duplicate name=%@", [object name]);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (explanation in the comments):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *wordString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words"
                                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                                error:NULL];

        // Get all the words by separating on newlines & convert to lowercase
        // Note: Assuming that the list doesn't contain duplicate strings
        // (i.e. the same word or name twice)
        // If it does, you should separate/add_to_set/get_all_objects/lowercase instead
        NSArray *words = [[wordString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] 
                           valueForKey:@"lowercaseString"];

        // Create a counted set to keep track of duplicate strings
        NSCountedSet *bag = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:words];

        // Create a mutable set to add only duplicates
        NSMutableSet *duplicates = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:0];

        // Iterate and add words that appear more than once in the counted set
        for (NSString *word in bag) {
            if ([bag countForObject:word] > 1) {
                [duplicates addObject:word];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"Words: %lu | Unique words: %lu | Duplicates: %lu", words.count, bag.count, duplicates.count);
        // Output => Words: 235887 | Unique words: 234372 | Duplicates: 1515
    }
}
```

Now `duplicates` is a Set of the strings that are both words & names (as per your requirement i.e. they only differ in the capitalization). You can get an array of the words by sending `[duplicates allObjects]`.